# Understanding PySpark Reduce()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, reduce

I'm learning Spark with PySpark and I'm trying different staff with the function reduce() to properly understand it, but I did something and obtained a result that makes no sense to me.

The previous examples I executed with reduce was basic things like:

```
>>> a = sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> a.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
'abcd'

>>> a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
>>> a.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
10

>>> a = sc.parallelize(['azul','verde','azul','rojo','amarillo'])
>>> aV2 = a.map(lambda x:(x,1))
>>> aRes = aV2.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
>>> aRes.collect()
[('rojo', 1), ('azul', 2), ('verde', 1), ('amarillo', 1)]
```

But I tried this:

```
>>> a = sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> a.reduce(lambda x,y:x+x)
'aaaaaaaa'
```

And I was expecting 'aaaa' as a result but no 'aaaaaaaa'

I was looking for an answers reading reduce() docs but I think I'm missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your x in lambda function is keep changing and so the x of last expression in each step is

```
a
aa 
aaaa
```

which gives the last result `aaaaaaaa`. The number of character should be doubled with your expression.